# Linear regression with R: How do I get labels on data point in qq plot, scale location plot, Residuals vs Leverage etc

Tags: r, plot, label, linear-regression

I have a small dataset with EU member states that contains values on their degree of negotiation success and the activity level the member states showed in the negotiations.

I am doing a linear regression with R.

In short the hypothesis is:
The more activity a member state shows, the more success it will have in negotiations.

I played around a lot with the data, transformed it etc.

What I have done so far:

```
# Stored the dataset from a csv file in object linData
linData = read.csv(file.choose(), sep = ";", encoding = "de_DE.UTF-8")

# As I like to switch variables and test different models, I send the relevant ones to objects x and y.
# So it is easier for me to change it in the future.
x = linData$ALL_Non_Paper_Art.Ann.Recit.Nennung
y = linData$Success_high

# I put the label for each observation in a factor lab
lab = linData$MS_short

# After this I run the linear model
linModel = lm(y~x, data = linData)
summary(linModel)

# I create a simple scatterplot. Here the labels from the factor lab work fine
plot(x, y)
text(x, y, labels=lab, cex= 0.5, pos = 4)
```

So far so good. Now I want to check for model quality. For visual insepection I found out I can use the command

```
plot(linModel)
```

This produces 4 plots in a row:

- [Residuals vs Fitted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SpGCf.png)
- [Normal Q-Q](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yssYZ.png)
- [Scale Location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PpvJT.png)
- [Residuals vs Leverage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3R8jY.png)

As you can see in every picture R marks problematic observations by a number. It would be very convenient if R could just use the column "MS_short" from te dataset and add the label to the marked observations. I am sure this is possible... but how?

I work with R for 2 months now. I found some stuff here and via googe but nothing helped me to solve the problem. I have no one I can ask. This is my 1st post here an stackoverflow.

Thank you in advance
Rainer

Comment: `plot.lm` has a `labels.id` argument.  See `?plot.lm`

Comment: Thank you, I will try that.

Answer (score 1):

With the help of G. Grothendieck I solved the problem.

After entering the R-help of plot, more specific the help for plot and linear regression (plot.lm) with the command

```
?plot.lm
```

I read the box with the "arguments and usage" part and identified the **labels.id** argument AND the **id.n** argument.

**id.n** is "number of points to be labelled in each plot, starting with the most extreme."

I needed that. I was interested in the identification of this extreme points. R already marked the 3 most extreme points in all graphics (see initial post) but used the observations numbers and not any useful labels. Any other labelling would mess up the graphics. So, we remember: In my case I want the 3 most extreme values to be labelled.

Now let's add this to the command:
I started the same as above, with a plot of my already computed linear model -> plot(linModel). After that I added "**id.n =**" and set the value to "**3**". That looked like that:

```
plot(linModel, id.n = 3,
```

So far so good, now R knows what to label BUT still not what should be used as label.
For this we have to add the **labels.id** to the command.

**labels.id** is the "vector of labels, from which the labels for extreme points will be chosen."

I assumed that one column in my dataset (NOT the linear model!) has the property of a vector and so I added a comma and then "**labels.id =**" to the command and typed in the name of my dataset and then the column, so in my case: "linData$MS_short" where linData is the dataset and MS_short the column with the 2 letter string for each member state. The final command looked like this:

```
plot(linModel, id.n = 3, labels.id = linData$MS_short)
```

And then it worked (see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mruoj.png)). End of story.

Hope this can help some other newbies. Greetings.